# How to a add a file when a .gitignore is already present on that folder?

Tags: git, gitignore

As I've been told, git doesn't recognize folders *de per se*.
In order to have the folder to be on the repo, but not the files inside we did create a .gitignore file inside that folder with the following inside:

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
```

It happens however that, inside that directory, we now need to add a new file that SHOULD be tracked by the git.

How can we proceed ?

Should we, do the steps on the following order ?

1. Change to:

   ```
   # Ignore everything in this directory
   *
   # Except this file
   !.gitignore
   !mynewfile.php
   ```
2. `git add mynewfile.php`
3. `git commit -a -m "added new file inside specific folder"`
4. `git push` (so that my remote hub knows about this and syncs with master so that all stay equal).

Or, should we proceed differently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you suggest are OK, but step 1) is unneeded as there's no need to change your `.gitignore` file, just add it with `--force` flag and commit it.

Listing files in `.gitignore` tell git that they are meant to be untracked, but it doesn't prevent you to track them. It applies only to untracked files, there's nothing wrong into having tracked files listed in it.

Comment: I may be missing the logic, can you please elaborate further? I mean, if we don't place that !mynewfile.php then, what is the * really doing there ?

Comment: Sure I'm talking about `*` files in the .gitignore. What I'm saying is that you don't need to specify `!myfile` in the gitignore before adding it. Hope it's clearer

Comment: I thought that, if I don't specify, `!myfile` on .gitignore, it will tell git to ignore myfile, due to the `*` there present. But you are telling me that, I don't need that !myfile there, because, git will track it anyway ? (please have patience)

Comment: if you don't add `!myfile` on .gitignore, git will list `myfile` as untracked when asking for status. But, if you `git add myfile`, and commit, there's no need to "un-ignore" it since it's then tracked.

Comment: Well, your answer is given, and it works. I will leave the "Why does .gitignore apply only to untracked files, and why isn't there nothing wrong into having tracked files listed" for another post.

Comment: One last question please. If we start a new project, with `myfile` already present on that folder. We can still keep the .gitignore file defined as it is ?

Comment: Can't add it: :s `The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
public_html/assets/resize/resizer.php
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16355/discussion-between-charlesb-and-mem)

Answer (score 1):

`git add -f the_ignored_file`

Allows you to add ignored file.